# How to convert a binary file to a numpy file?

Tags: python

I need to convert a binary file 'file.bin' to a numpy file 'file.npy',
I hope that you could help me because I don't find any solution.

Comment: Does this help ?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html

Comment: I have already seen that , but it doesn't give the binary type.

Comment: If you do not know the data type it is impossible to extract the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a text of binary values to numpy file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903274/convert-a-text-of-binary-values-to-numpy-file)

Comment: No, It isn't a duplicate question because I am talking about converting all the binary file to another numpy file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the file with [`np.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) into an array and then `np.save` this array. You can specify the structure of the binary file using the `dtype` which can be a struct too.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.fromfile('file.bin', dtype=np.float64)
np.save('file.npy', arr)

# optional to delete old file
import os
os.remove('file.bin')
```

[`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) is helpful too, if it is a large file or you want to specify an `offset`.